# Python urllib read url specific lines faster

Tags: python, urllib

I managed to access a robot web server and read out data on lines 166 to 171. This happens every 0.08 second (80 ms), see **code** blow. Using Python version 3.6.

```
print("Begin")

import urllib.request
import time

#! INIT
i = 0
d_coordinate = {}

while(i < 100):
    t0 = time.time()
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.41.110/MD/CURPOS.DG")

    #Loop CURPOS
    for line_number, line in enumerate(response):
        if(line_number >= 166 and line_number <= 171): 
            #Zet de volledig uitgelezen line in array: response_lines
            response_lines = [line]

            #Filteren van data, wegschrijven in dictonary: d_coordinate 
            for line in response_lines:
                key = line.split(b':')[0].decode()
                value = float(line.split(b' ')[-1])
                d_coordinate[key] = value
               
    i = i + 1
    print(d_coordinate)
    t1 = time.time()
    total = t1-t0
    
    print ("Total Cyclic time: ", total)
    print("\n\n")
```

**Output (2 loops)**

```
{'X': 485.01, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': 394.98, 'W': -180.0, 'P': 0.0, 'R': 0.0}
Total Cyclic time:  0.08749628067016602

{'X': 485.01, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': 394.98, 'W': -180.0, 'P': 0.0, 'R': 0.0}
Total Cyclic time:  0.0803687572479248
```

Every time the entire file is read and this of course cost a considerable amount of time. Is there a possibility to directly look only at lines 166 - 171?

Answer (score 0):

You might use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get lines you want following way:
add `import itertools` then replace:

```
for line_number, line in enumerate(response):
    if(line_number >= 166 and line_number <= 171):
```

using:

```
for line_number, line in itertools.islice(enumerate(response), 166, 172):
```

Note that there is `172` as opposed to `171` as `itertools.islice` convention is compliant with python index slicing i.e. inclusive-exclusive.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Your solution works fine, only the program still achieves the same speed of 80 ms.

Comment: Any other solutions?

Comment: I do not have any ready solution for you. Only thing I might suggest is more fine-grained time measuring. How many time is consuming retrievieng response and how many time loop? How fast would it be if you would comment whoule for - if main time-consumer is retrieving optimizing lopp will not help.

Comment: Without any code, just urllib the code will need 0.08 seconds indeed. Is there another way around to get the data faster? Threads, multiprocessing..?